# Is it possible to create a class property that is a combination of other properties?

Tags: c#

I want to combine a few string properties into a single string to make sorting and display easier. I was wondering if there was a way to do this without having to iterate through the collection or list of the class. Something like FullName in the below Person class.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Last {get;set;}
    public string First {get;set;}

    public string FullName = Last + ", " + First {get;}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update your class like so:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }

    public string FullName 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return string.Format("{0}, {1}", First, Last); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Additional to your question, I would also recommend implementing an override of the `ToString()` method (your question mentions making display easier) as most UI technologies will use this as a default way of displaying an object.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return FullName;
}
```

Comment: I like this one the best but you accidentally swapped First and Last

Answer (score 3):

```
public string FullName {
  get{
    return Last + ", " + First;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
public string FullName 
{
    get
    {
        return FirstName + ", " + LastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is a great example of the phenomena of someone with high rep getting upvoted more than people with low rep. :)

Comment: @aquinas yeah true, its weird to see how some answers get more votes even tho they're completely identical to others

Comment: It's called social proof. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_proof . Part of being human.

Comment: Please use the comments section for on-topic discussions. If you don't have anything constructive to say about the specific question being asked here or the specific answer and would like to start a discussion about the social behavior on StackOverflow don't hesitate to do so on http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

Why not?

```
public string FullName
{
    get { return Last + ", " + First; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  public string FullName 
     {
          get
            {
                return Last + " " + First;    
            }        
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public string Fullname
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}", Last, First);
    }
    set
    {
        string[] temp = value.Split(',');
        Last = temp[0].Trim();
        First = temp[1].Trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use a property in your class to do the same. Even Microsoft advises to make a void method in a class which just do simple operations with the fields of a class as a property instead of a method.

Answer (score 0):

> Use string interpolation, as it is easy and simple ;)

```
    public class ApplicationUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }


        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
            }
        }
    }
```